# Is a newly added field available for BQL to query in database?

Tags: acumatica

Hopefully it is not a stupid question - can I use BQL to query a new field that I just added through customization in database?

I just added a new field to "contract" table through "System->Customization" - I created a project there and added a new field called "ProductCode" (it automatically became "UsrProductCode" in database), and the field does show in "contract" table as well as the "contract template" screen (CT202000) after successful compilation and publish, exactly as I expected, however, I got error:

```
 The type name 'UsrProductCode' does not exist in the type 'PX.Objects.CT.Contract' in file: Code#SOOrderEntry(80)
```

when I then tried to use this field in a BQL as below:

```
// Lookup contract template ID
   Contract template = PXSelect<Contract,
                                Where<Contract.isTemplate, Equal<boolTrue>, And<Contract.UsrProductCode, Equal<Required<Contract.UsrProductCode>>>>>
                            .Select(Base, inventoryCD);
```

I thought adding new field through customization would automatically make it available for BQL query but it seems I was wrong - what would I need to do in order to make it be able to be used in BQL?

Thanks for your help.

Edited:

Following suggestion from @Jeff Williams, I tried to find out the class definition file related to my customization - the only file I found is "PX_Objects_CT_Contract_extensions.cs", which is under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\AcumaticaERP\App_Code\Caches" and the code is very simple as below:

```
public class PX_Objects_CT_Contract_Extension_AddColumn: PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CT.Contract>{

        #region UsrProductCode

        [PXDBString(30)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Product Code")]

        public virtual string UsrProductCode{get;set;}
        public abstract class usrProductCode : IBqlField{}

        #endregion
```

I also tried to use "PX_Objects_CT_Contract_Extension_AddColumn.UsrProductCode" in BQL and got error during compilation:

```
'PX_Objects_CT_Contract_Extension_AddColumn.UsrProductCode' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type' in file:
```

Can somebody tell me what else I need to do to make this new field available for BQL?

Comment: What version of acumatica ERP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does add it however you cannot reference it as "Contract.Usr..." it would be under something like "ContractExtension.Usr...".

Look at the data class where the DAC extension is and see what that name is.  If your BQL is in a different name space you will need to add a reference to the codeclass namespace as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn't work for me - please see the new edits I made to my post.

Comment: Try this:  Contract template = PXSelect<Contract,
                                Where<Contract.isTemplate, Equal<boolTrue>, And<PX_Objects_CT_Contract_Extension_AddColumn.usrProductCode, Equal<Required<PX_Objects_CT_Contract_Extension_AddColumn.usrProductCode>>>>>
                            .Select(Base, inventoryCD);

Comment: I think that is exactly what I tried and I got error as I indicated in my post above.

Comment: from the code you pasted above you used the uppercase (UsrProductCode) which isn't correct.  You need to reference the IBqlField which is the lowercase (usrProductCode)

Comment: It worked! Thank you  so much! I noticed yours was lower case but thought that was typo...thanks again!